# How to find differentiation and integration of curves in general?

Tags: integration, derivatives, graphing-functions, curves

Graph of function $f(x)$

[image]

How do I go about finding integration and differentiation of curves like these which yield other curves?

Comment: It's just like integration of any other function, except that you need to look at the graph to estimate the function; you have no equation you can work with. But this is a multiple choice question, which makes it easier because three of the four choices are completely the wrong functions and can quickly be eliminated.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concepts and definitions of integration? What can you say about $F(0)$ (integral of $f$ from $-5$ to $0$). Is it greater than $0$? Greater than $3$? Less than $-17$?

Comment: I know that integration gives area under that curve. For F(0) I calculated the area from -5 to 0(Divided that region into two triangles and one rectangle) and it equals 8. So going by options only D has F(0) has positive. But for F(-1) and F(1) the value remains same . That doesn't makes sense. Does it?

Comment: You're trying to be too precise. It's a sketch. The area on the left could be -8 or a similar number near it, there's also no vertical scale on the integrals, so that doesn't help much. You are meant to observe the big picture, no brute force calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a little bit of instinct for these things. Sure, you can just go and check the slope. But there are other signs as well. First of all, an integral of an odd function is even and vice-versa (if you disregard the constant offset). So, (A) and (B) are immediately out. Then, recall that integration *smooths* things. So integrating a discontinuous function makes a continuous one, a continuous piecewise linear becomes a smooth one with continuous derivative (no sharp angles) and so on. That rules out (D) and (B). Even more... you know that integrating a linear function gives a quadratic one. So the segments that are linear in the original function are parabolic in the result and constant parts become linear in the result. This makes it easy to sketch the curve by hand.

You can see that going forward (integrating) instead of trying backward (differentiating) also has a lot of clues and tricks, I'd say it's even more convenient than differentiation, because it's easier to see (integration makes for global properties, differentiation is local, so you must "probe" the function at different places). Of course, everything you know about differential properties of curves also applies (zero derivative is an extremum,...).

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. But what do you say about F(0). Shouldn't it be positive as the area under the curve $f(x)$ from intervals -5 to 0 yields value 8?

Comment: No, the area under the curve on the left half is negative, because it's under the axis.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Now when I read all these answers, it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

As $f$ is odd, $F$ must be even. This excludes (A) and (B). And $(D)$ is excluded because its derivative is zero in all the interval except in a finite number of points (where doesn't exists).